# Text selected and highlighted in yellow in an HTML page from the URL

Tags: google-chrome, url, firefox, safari

Google has recently pushed (June 2020) a new feature in Chrome which allow to select and highlight in yellow some texts in a web page by passing the information from the URL.

Here is an example:

```
https://www.google.com/#:~:text=About
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

This is Google Chrome specific but doesn't require any extension. Firefox doesn't support it (as of June 2020). Safari seems to be "compliant". [Here is an article mentioning this feature.](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/4/21280115/google-search-engine-yellow-highlight-featured-snippet-anchor-text)

Question: Where is/What is the exact spec? What can I do or cannot do with the ":~:"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some explanations here:

https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment

If you have Chrome ;-), here is the link to highlight the relevant part!

https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment#:~:text=Proposed%20Solution

Comment: For more details, read the [article](https://web.dev/text-fragments/).